# Why not row and column operations together?

Tags: linear-algebra

On  a  matrix  we  apply  either  elementary  row  or  elementary  column  operation but  never  both  of  them  together. I  am recently  learning  these  elementary  operations.This  is  being  used  to  compute  inverse  or  solve  a  system  of  linear  equations. I  need  to  know  what  algebraically  happens  to  the  matrix or  the  operator  here  when  we  do  the  elementary  operations  and  what  goes  wrong  if  we  try  to  do  a  row  operation  followed  by  a  column  operation  or  two  row(/column)  at  the  same  time.

Comment: Any elementary row operation corresponds to the left multiplication by a very simple invertible matrix. Any column operation - to the right multiplication by a similar looking matrix. Since matrix multiplication is associative, those operations commute, so nothing dangerous can happen if we do them in whatever order.

Comment: In numerical practice Gaussian elimination combines elementary row operations with column swaps to obtain nonzero entries ("pivots") needed to create leading ones in upper rows.  Search for Gaussian elimination with pivoting.

Answer (score 2):

Please do correct me if I misunderstood, or if what I say is incorrect.

Consider matrix $$A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{array} \right).$$
Saying $$A \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y\end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right)$$
is equivalent to saying$$\begin{cases}x + y = a \\ x- y = b\end{cases}.$$
Row operations correspond to adding multiplying equations. Column operations would correspond to adding $x$ to $y$ which clearly messes things up.

Comment: Adding the second row to the first row is done by multiplication $\left[\matrix{1 & 1\\0 & 1}\right]A$. Adding the second column to the first column is done by $A\left[\matrix{1 & 0\\1 & 1}\right]$. Both operations are harmless in the sense that one can roll the things back multiplying by their inverses. Of course, one has to keep tracking what has been done so far. Exception is when one is solving a linear system, then the order of the equations is irrelevant, so the row operations are preferably easier.

Comment: I assume that what OP is actually asking is: "How can I think about the row operations in Gaussian elimination?" In that context adding both rows and columns does not make sense.

Comment: I think the same, the whole point of Gaussian elimination is to simplify calculated of the equations in linear system. If we apply elementary operations on columns it is like adding two different variable outside coefficient matrix. Also swapping the columns will make the path to solution more complicated as you need to keep the track of the variables in $x$ matrix or constant matrix $b$ ($Ax = b$) which again is not in scope of what this algorithm tries to simplify.